# Web application not working on latest chrome version

Tags: java, spring, google-chrome, browser, web-applications

I am using already preset web software which is made from spring framework, java, neo4j database management system, tomcat server.

It was working on chrome Version 62.0.3202.94 (Official Build) (64-bit). But as new version arrives (Version 63.0.3239.84 (Official Build) (64-bit)) it is not showing any queried data on the UI. But I can see in the log that query is successfully completed.

Is there any reason that this application is not working on the latest version of chrome?

Also it is not working on any other web browser.

Developer console of browser shows below error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: The comparison function must be either a function or undefined
    at Array.sort (native)
    at displayFileNameCountMap (http://localhost:8080/code/js/graph.js:49:10)
    at XMLHttpRequest.xmlhttp1.onreadystatechange (http://localhost:8080/code/js/core.js:57:13)
```

Comment: You do not provide enough information. Open Developer Console in Chrome and look for any errors, network requests result and so on. It's impossible to answer for not completed answer.

Comment: @AlexeySviridov Added the details from developer console.

Comment: Seems like new chrome more strict in type checking. Actually it's looks like bug in graph.js file, it contain some incompatibility with latest Chrome. Check for new version, may be it fixed already

Comment: @AlexeySviridov Already using the latest veriosn

Comment: Bad luck... Only i can suggest to you - fire bug to graph.js developers and manually fix your graph.js at line 49 to apply some workaround. Actually you problem doesn't relay on any server-side component like spring or so, your browser just can't execute js file